# ¿Como iterar o recorrer un objecto de la clase Object que contiene objetos de distinta clase en su interior?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Tengo esta query en hql:

```
String lHql = " from  Grupo g"
                + " join g.Persona p " 
                + " join g.Animal a "
                + " where g.tipo= "A"";
        Query lQuery = pSession.createQuery(lHql);

        Object lResult  = (Object) lQuery.uniqueResult();
```

El problema es que me devuelve 3 objetos distintos (Grupo, Persona y Animal). Si solo devolviera Grupo asignaria el resultado a un objeto Grupo y listo. No me deja asignar el resultado a un Arraylist, solo puedo asignarle a la clase genérica Object. Debugando se ve claramente que la variable LResult tiene 3 objetos dentro, cada uno con sus atributos.
EL problema es que no se como ir a buscar esos objetos y recogerlos, no me deja pues lResult no es un array.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando hql (Hibernate o similar), lo común es que traigas un Objeto principal de la BD y otros objetos relacionados, para lo cual tendrías que determinar cuál es el objeto principal de tu consulta, digamos que es Grupo. Tu clase Grupo debería tener todos sus atributos y además un atributo "Persona" y un atributo "Animal", ésta es la gracia del hql. traer todos los objetos relacionados de un golpe.

```
public class Grupo(){
  private int grupoId;
  ...
  @OneToMany
  private Persona persona;
  @OneToMany
  private Animal animal;
  ...
}
```

y de ésta forma solo obtienes tu objeto Grupo y después puedes hacer algo como

```
Grupo grupo = //obtener grupo desde BD
grupo.getPersona();
```

Y ahí deberías de poder ver todos los atributos de persona
Saludos

Comment: La solución finalmente es: "Select g from  Grupo g". Remarcar que devuelva el objeto grupo y de esta forma no me devuelve los 3. No se si te referías exactamente a esto...

Comment: Yo te entendí que querías traer la información de los tres objetos, mediante HQL, pero ahora veo que solo necesitabas Grupo. De la manera que te comento, traes la lista de objetos Grupo, con sus respectivos objetos Persona y Animal

Answer (score 0):

Una manera es guardar en un arreglo como objeto cada elemento que recuperas y luego lo seleccionas y almacenas en una clase o variable de interes segun lo clasifiques.

ejm

```
public void resultados(){
    List<Object> valoresMixtos = new ArrayList<>();
    valoresMixtos.add(new Empleado(0, "Andres", "Ventas", 32.5));
    valoresMixtos.add(new Entidad(2, "1258475", "Juan", "Nov"));
    valoresMixtos.add(new Empleado(0, "Ramon", "Ventas", 32.5));

    valoresMixtos.forEach(elemento ->{
        if(elemento instanceof Empleado) System.out.println("Tipo Empleado");
        if(elemento instanceof Entidad) System.out.println("Tipo Entidad");
    });

}
```